# Pattern matching for custom data constructor similar to lists

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

I have a data constructor defined like this:

```
data Stack a = Empty | NonEmpty a (Stack a)
         deriving (Show, Read, Eq)
```

Then I have a function which uses it with pattern matching:

```
func :: Stack a -> a
func (Stack.NonEmpty val Stack.Empty) = ...
func (Stack.NonEmpty val1 (Stack.NonEmpty val2 Stack.Empty)) = ...
```

What I would like to do is doing the pattern matching similar way the Sequence or List does it using an operator like this:

```
func :: Stack a -> a
func (val :> Stack.Empty) = ...
func (val1 :> val2 :> Stack.Empty) = ...
```

I know it actually isn't an operator but a data constructor which looks like an operator but I wasn't able to make it work.

Also I started learning Haskell a few weeks ago.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define `:>` as data constructor instead of `NonEmpty`:

```
data Stack a = Empty | a :> Stack a
    deriving (Show, Read, Eq)
```

then the only thing you still need to do is specify this as a *right-associative* operator such that `x :> y :> z` is parsed as `x :> (y :> z)`:

```
data Stack a = Empty | a :> Stack a
    deriving (Show, Read, Eq)

infixr 7 :>
```

Here is `7` the *fixity* and determine what takes precedence if there are two operators.

Comment: Thank you very much.